# JavaScript Calculate time difference in known intervals

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, intervals

I'm Struggling with calculation of date time objects :(

We're getting three inputs from the user:

```
1. Start time of day
2. End time of day
3. Intervals between events (in minutes)
```

My target goal is to **calculate how many events I have every day from start time to end time by the selected interval**, and creating an array with the exact times of these events.

So far I'm getting the data in this way:

`StartTime` is a Datetime object.
`EndTime` is a Datetime object.

```
//Get start time    
var HourOfStart = StartTime.getHours();
var MinuteOfStart = StartTime.getMinutes();

//Get end time    
var HourOfEnd = EndTime.getHours();
var MinuteOfEnd = EndTime.getMinutes();
```

After calculating the differences of how many events in an hour and trying to cap the first and last events, I realised I must be doing something wrong *(math is not my strong suit)*. Also converting to a unix timestamp got me baffled, because the events aren't starting at a round hour.

**So in a nutshell, if the user enters:**

```
Start time: 10:15
End time: 12:30
Interval: 15 minutes
```

**I need to get the following array of event times:**
`10:30,10:45,11:00,11:15,11:30,11:45,12:00,12:15`

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't try to do arithmetic with hours and minutes. Use `getTime` to get the full time in milliseconds. Then just divide by the number of milliseconds in the intervals.

Comment: @Barmar Damn I'm so stupid, must be the long hours. I'l write it up and post it here for future bobble heads :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that should do what you want. As suggested in the comments, just calculate the time in milliseconds and increment until you reach your stop time.

```js
function calculate() {
  var a = [];
  var startValue = document.getElementById("startTime").value;
  var endValue = document.getElementById("endTime").value;
  var intervalValue = document.getElementById("interval").value;
  var startDate = new Date("1/1/2015 " + startValue);
  var endDate = new Date("1/1/2015 " + endValue);
  var offset = intervalValue * 1000 * 60;
  do {
    startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + offset);
    if (startDate < endDate)
      a.push(startDate);
  } while(startDate < endDate);
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<label for="startTime">Start Time</label>
<input id="startTime" value="10:15" />
<br/>
<label for="endTime">End Time</label>
<input id="endTime" value="12:30" />
<br/>
<label for="interval">Interval</label>
<input id="interval" value="15" />
<br/>
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Calculate" />
```